# Change the URL of node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've just deployed my first `AngularJS` application to *Heroku* using *Node* with the script below.

Now the *URL* to the site is *http://project.herokuapp.com/*. However, I would like it to be *http://project.herokuapp.com/beta*. How can I accomplish this?

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
 
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + ""));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With express (4x) [`Router()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) you can do that. For example:

```
// declare your router
var router = express.Router();

// define your routes
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // do your stuff  
});

// define other routes and so on...

// ...and make shure all your routes will be prefixed with /beta
app.use('/beta', router);
```

Now, `http://project.herokuapp.com/beta` is the main path, and other routes will be always prefixed with `/beta`